# Rails: Empty fields are creating the string 'undefined' in database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

For some reason when users are skipping optional fields signing up, the database is filled with the string 'undefined' instead of NULL or a blank string.

I am using Rails 2.3.4 and MySQL.

Is this a known bug/issue for earlier versions of Rails?

Thank you,
Eric

Comment: Could you post your controller and view code please?

Answer (score 0):

Add a `:default` option in the field of your schema to what you want

```
:default => null
```

or

```
:default => ""
```

Will work.